# Creating subset based on string conditions

Tags: r

Havig a dataframe like this:

```
df_in <- data.frame(x = c('x1','x2','x3','x4'),
                     col1 = c('http://youtube.com/something','NA','https://www.yahooexample.com','https://www.yahooexample2.com'),
                     col2 = c('https://google.com', 'http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321','NA','https://google.com/text'),
                     col3 = c('http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321', 'http://google.com?id=1234','NA','https://bbcnews.com/search'),
                     col4 = c('NA', 'https://www.youtube/com','NA', 'www.youtube.com/searcht'))
```

Example of dataframe input as printed in the console:

> ```
>  x                          col1                           col2                          col3                    col4
> 1 x1  http://youtube.com/something             https://google.com http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321                      NA
> 2 x2                            NA http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321     http://google.com?id=1234 https://www.youtube/com
> 3 x3  https://www.yahooexample.com                             NA                            NA                      NA
> 4 x4 https://www.yahooexample2.com        https://google.com/text    https://bbcnews.com/search www.youtube.com/searcht
> ```

I would like to create a dataframe of a specific subset conditions. Example I would like to keep only the one which contain the "google", "youtube" and "bbc" in their sting.
Example of expected output:

```
df_out <- data.frame(x = c('x1','x2','x4'),
                     col1new = c('http://youtube.com/something', 'http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321', 'https://google.com/text'),
                     col2new = c('https://google.com', 'http://google.com?id=1234', 'https://bbcnews.com/search'),
                     col3new = c('http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321', 'https://www.youtube/com', 'www.youtube.com/searcht'))
```

Example of dataframe output as printed in the console:

> ```
>  x                        col1new                    col2new                       col3new
> 1 x1   http://youtube.com/something         https://google.com http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321
> 2 x2 http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321  http://google.com?id=1234       https://www.youtube/com
> 3 x4        https://google.com/text https://bbcnews.com/search       www.youtube.com/searcht
> ```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What happens when your search team is your condition? For example `bbc` in `youtube`? `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bbc`

Comment: You may need `i1 <- Reduce('|', lapply(df_in[-1], grepl, pattern= "googlel|youtube|bbc"));  cbind(df_in[i1, 1, drop = FALSE], t(apply(df_in[i1,-1], 1,  function(x) x[grepl("google|youtube|bbc", x)])))`

Comment: What should be the output for : `df_in <- data.frame(x = c('x1','x2','x3','x4' ,'x5'), col1 = c('http://youtube.com/something','NA','https://www.yahooexample.com','https://www.yahooexample2.com', 'www.youtube.com/searcht'), col2 = c('https://google.com', 'http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321','NA','https://google.com/text', 'www.youtube.com/searcht'),
col3 = c('http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321', 'http://google.com?id=1234','NA','https://bbcnews.com/search', 'www.youtube.com/searcht'),
col4 = c('NA', 'https://www.youtube/com','NA', 'www.youtube.com/searcht', 'www.youtube.com/searcht')
 )` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a logical condition with `grep` to filter the rows based on the entries of elements having atleast one of the pattern after the `http://`

```
i1 <- Reduce('|', lapply(df_in[-1], grepl, pattern= "https?://(google|youtube|bbc)"))
```

Then, loop through the rows of the subset data and get the links that match with `google/youtube/bbc`

```
tmp <- t(apply(df_in[i1,-1], 1, function(x) x[grepl("(google|youtube|bbc)", x)]))
colnames(tmp) <- paste0('col', seq_len(ncol(tmp)), "new")
```

and `cbind` with the subset of first column

```
cbind(df_in[i1, 1, drop = FALSE], tmp)
#   x                        col1new                    col2new                       col3new
#1 x1   http://youtube.com/something         https://google.com http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321
#2 x2 http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321  http://google.com?id=1234       https://www.youtube/com
#4 x4        https://google.com/text https://bbcnews.com/search       www.youtube.com/searcht
```